# Two communicative patterns: how typical are they?

Tags: узус, социолингвистика

Recently Russian has obtained two more clichés of which I am not quite certain how to use them properly. The clichés are

> a) вот это вот (всё)

Is this a humorous pattern or should it be taken seriously? When is it normally used?

The other one is something I call 'explanative ellipsis'. It is typically represented in b) monologous speech going like this:

> Statement A. =>
>  
>   => Ну как [Statement A repeated]? =>
>   => Statement A elaborated transforming into Statement B.

Comment: Point b) is not clear for me, will you give an example with complete sentences?

Comment: Ну вот написАл я вопрос в эту вашу систему. Ну то есть как написал? Взял, подумал, решил запостить там, буквы набрал всякие, значки, вот это всё...

Comment: It's a typical Russian way of speaking, it doesn't seem any new to me. Only "Ну, то есть, как написал?" must have 2 commas.

Answer (score 5):

As for point a), it's an Internet meme. It originated from this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24XBX0Wkmpw). Света из Иваново is speaking uneducated Russian, the phrase is `овощи, там, рожь, вот это всё`. Another meme from this video is `более лучше`, which is surely ungrammatical.

The phrase `вот это всё` is used jokingly, after an enumeration, like

> Я люблю разных зверей: котиков, собачек, зайчиков, вот это всё.

Comment: Алсо, люди не из интернетов не оценят этого лулза чуть более, чем полностью.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's worth to clarify that phrase `вот это всё` is grammatically correct and before that video it was not humorous. But the whole sentence `овощи, там, рожь, вот это всё` renders the speaker unable to build fine sentences and inexperienced in formal speech.

And, as Yellow Sky already said, b) is not new, it's widely used in oral speech.

(I hope I have not messed up English grammar too much :))